# Session Timeout in sitecore powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

[![Ideal Session Timeout in Powershell console][1]][1]

[image]
I have noticed this few times before & I have intentionally recreated today to confirm on how console would respond when there is a session timeout.

Other dialogs, windows or applications/modules in Sitecore would redirect to login page when we have session timeout case & I was expecting similar behavior with PowerShell console.

Please correct me if I am missing or misconception on this?

FYI: I have explicitly set SessionState timeout to 1 min :(
*Does this behavior applies to Powershell ISE ?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking, exactly. I think it's pretty clear that the way SPE handles session timeouts is by showing that message in the console.

Comment: When there is a session timeout in Sitecore client we were not redirected to login screen while scripting in Powershell console. But we receive message as shown in the snapshot. is that the expected behavior ? Hope it clarifies now.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko You might be aware that when the same timeout happens in Powershell SPE it redirects to login screen. When the message is possible in Powershell console & why couldn't the redirect to login screen be possible. Make sense ?

Comment: Asking whether SPE behaviour is expected or not, is fine. Debating how you would _like_ it to work however, falls out of scope for this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

The Sitecore Powershell Console is designed, so that it can operate and "reconnect" to sessions that have otherwise timed out.  It is not directly linked to your Sitecore Desktop session.

(I'm not a guru when it comes to SPE, but that's how I read it).

Reference: http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/26/sitecore-powershell-extensions-persistent-sessions/

Where it states:

> This is because the Console enables you to keep continuity between the
>   commands you execute and in fact is handled completely differently
>   than the other interactions – through a web service.

Comment: thanks for your reply. From the background operation perspective its absolutely fine, i.e. continue the process when the session is back but when powershell console is part of the Sitecore Client Interface & would expect to redirect to login screen since i cannot continue scripting unless i'm authenticated which is possible through sitecore login screen. Please correct if i'm still wrong.

Comment: I believe this has changed since version 4.3 of SPE with Session State Elevation which is set to 5 minutes by default for ISE and the console: https://sitecorepowershell.com/session-state-elevation/

Answer (score 2):

Since the release of SPE 4.3 a new concept of Session State Elevation was introduced which uses tokens to elevate your session to have temporary execution rights:
https://sitecorepowershell.com/session-state-elevation/

Session State Elevation requests show in ISE, Console, and when trying to view and save scripts in Content Editor, as well as when saving scripts in ISE.

By Default these for ISE and Console the timeout is set to 5 minutes.

The timeouts can be set in the Cognifide.PowerShell.config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <powershell>
      <userAccountControl>
        <gates>
          <!--
            Gates into the system
            Ways ARBITRARY (not already saved/existing in the system) scripts might make into the system without explicitly providing password during the execution or save.
            Those gates require that the user session needs to be elevated with a proper token.
            Tokens are defined in the sestion below. Once Gate is elevated with a token it can do its job until token is dropped or expires.
            -->
          <gate name="Console" token="Console"/>
          <gate name="ISE" token="ISE"/>
          <gate name="ItemSave" token="ItemSave"/>
        </gates>
        <tokens>
          <!-- 
            Tokens provide means of elevation of the user session. Token can be used by one or more gates. 
            E.g. You can use the same token for all gates.
              elevationAction
                Token elavation actions:
                  - Block - always block action
                  - Password - Ask for Password to elevate session
                  - Allow - Always allow to elevate session without asking
              expiration
                TimeSpan serialized for how long session should stay elevated.
          -->
          <token name="Default" expiration="00:00:00" elevationAction="Block"/>
          <token name="Console" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Password"/>
          <token name="ISE" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Password"/>
          <token name="ItemSave" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Password"/> 
        </tokens>
      </userAccountControl>
    </powershell>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is a useful post I found today on settling the ISE config to `elevationAction="Allow"` for local development:

https://sitecorebrasil.wordpress.com/2017/04/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-ever-wonder-how-to-elevate-your-session-without-having-to-provide-your-credentials-here-is-how/